# Bootstrap Dropdown is not working in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

I am new to rails development. I am creating one Rails app. In which I am using Bootstrap 4.0.0 beta. I have one navbar in particular div, (not on whole page). But problem is, dropdown is not working when I click on it. For that first I have to click on nav-brand first, then I can click on dropdown and it works. But it changes whole placings of navbar. and again if I click on nav-brand dropdown stops working.

I also tried putting it on whole page there is also same problem.

I have ruby-2.4.1, rails-5.1.3, bootstrap-4.0.0beta

Here is my /assets/stylesheets/application.css code

```
*= require bootstrap
```

And this is /assets/stylesheets/welcomeindex.css code

```
*= require bootstrap
*= require application

body, .jumbotron{
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 155px);
  //overflow: hidden;
}

.jumbotron{
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {

  .jumbotron{
    height: 100%;
  }

} 

.footer {
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 40px;
   line-height: 40px;
   background-color: #f5f5f5;

  .container {
    width: auto;
    max-width: 680px;
    padding: 0 15px;
  }
}
```

This application.js file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require popper
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

And this is welcomeindex.html.erb file:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Fest Management </title>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'welcomeindex', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="main-container" class="container-fluid">

      <div class="row">

        <div class="jumbotron col-lg-8 col-md-12">
        </div>

        <div class="jumbotron col-lg-4 col-md-12">

          <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbarCollapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Messages <b class="caret"></b></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Inbox</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Drafts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sent Items</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Trash</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
           </div>
        </nav>

      </div>

      <footer class="footer navbar-fixed-bottom">
         <div class="container">
           <span class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</span>
         </div>
      </footer>

     </div>

    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

So where am I missing? It would be great help.

**EDIT**
after solving the issue of dropdown click, I am getting the issue with CSS of navbar. when i expand dropdwon, rather than poping out of navabar area, it increases the height of navbar and shows whole list in it.

here is the edited index.html.erb file. Along with the edits suggested I have completely removed CSS references and still it giving the same problem for CSS.

```
<div id="main-container" class="container-fluid">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="jumbotron col-lg-8 col-md-12">
    </div>

    <div class="jumbotron col-lg-4 col-md-12">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbarCollapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown show">
              <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="CategoryDD" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Messages <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="CategoryDD">
                <li><a href="#">Inbox</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Drafts</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sent Items</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Trash</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>

    <footer class="footer navbar-fixed-bottom">
      <div class="container">
       <span class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</span>
     </div>
    </footer>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Is there any error in console?

Comment: no. it doed not get clicked even. (without clicking on nav-brand)

Answer (score 2):

Adding to application.js

```
//= require jquery-ui
```

right after

```
//= require jquery
```

worked for me like a charm.
Hopefully, this will solve someone's issue too.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't add `body` and `html` tags in a view. You also shouldn't add

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

All of this is usually already defined in `application.html.erb` which is the "skeleton" of your views.

Regarding your issue:

According to the documentation, you're missing an id on the `a` tag.

```
<div class="dropdown show">
  <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown link
  </a>

  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Try removing any custom classes you've added and simply use this snippet. Should work out of the box if you leave all their elements.

If it still doesn't work, try running this in your console:

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
```

And let us know if there is an error.

Comment: It mostly started working. but now the problem is with CSS. when open dropdown, rather than showing as popup out of the navbar, it increase the height of navbar as whole and displays complete list in it.

Comment: That's a separate issue, probably caused by your markup. As always, if you see a weird behaviour, it's probably caused by your custom CSS or javascript. Strip out everything which is custom and add it back step by step to see what it causing the issue. But without your updated code, we can't help you

Comment: ok, i will try to emove custom CSS and backtrack, but how i display my updated code? in my main question with edit note?

Comment: The biggest thing I am seeing is you are missing the nav-item class on your dropdown li and the dropdown-item class on your menu li's. Once you add those it should work fine.

Comment: Hey @GrahamSlick, I ran this command `$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()` from the console. 
This was the response `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dropdown is not a function at <anonymous>:1:23`

Comment: @DenisOluka my answer is 2 years old so if you use a newer version of bootstrap, APIs might have changed

Answer (score 0):

You have added bootstrap but not jquery. Since bootstrap depends on jquery you must also add it. Before Rails 5, jquery used to be default in Rails app but Rails team removed it after Rails 5. If you want to use it then you should add this gem to your Gemfile. Here is the link https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails

Comment: It is included. You can see the application.js here. And yes in gemfile also added with bundle install command.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue, but solved with this kind of doing...

Did you overwrite bootstrap CDN or install any kind of bootstrap things like example of:

```
 <!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

If you're having this kind of in `application.html.erb` then kindly remove all kind of this...

and clear all cdn links and add again bootstap link

Thank you.